# How to write a "Texture Breathing" shader in GLSL?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I'm working on a little 2d video game, and while searching the internet for things that are irrelevant to it, I found this video: http://vimeo.com/67886447
I really like it. I want it.

### The author outline the process:

> The effect is produced by computing the vector derivative of a source
> photo then applying iterative advection along the resulting axes. A
> secondary scalar field controls and strength and magnitude of
> advection and allows a range of interesting effects including pulsing,
> waving and breathing.

As I understand it: a gradient field is computed, then the pixels are moved in the direction and magnitude of the corresponding vectors. Time is a multiplier of the vector magnitude, I'm guessing.

So, I think, I understand the process in my head, but since I'm kind of a newbie at GLSL, and shaders in general, I'm not sure how to write the code.

### This is how I see the code outline so far:

Iterate through the image, to fill a matrix with vectors resulted from using some sort of edge detection algorithm.
Iterate through the image once more and displace all pixels by vector magnitude*time.

### Few specific questions:

Would this even work, performance wise (on an average PC, of course)?

Is it possible to use the simple edge detection algorithm (checking the 8 nearby pixels, comparing the difference between that, and keep that as the magnitude, the direction of the vector will decided by the angle between the 2 pixels with the greatest difference).

How would I displace the pixels? I'd imagine moving a pixel would either leave a blank space at the place where it was, or, if I clone the pixel, there would be a lot of strange overlaying and the image would turn out bad.

### EDITS:

I just realized that doing it in one pass would be better: calculating the vector, then moving the pixel right away. What do you think?

I guess, I was wrong to use, and think of it as iterations.

This is the code I got so far. It is simple and it does it only along +x axis.

```
uniform float time;
uniform vec2 mouse;
uniform vec2 resolution;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;
uniform sampler2D u_texture; //diffuse map

void main( void ) {



vec2 pos = vec2(1,0);
vec4 px1 = texture2D(u_texture, vTexCoord+(pos/resolution));
vec4 dif =  px1 - texture2D(u_texture, vTexCoord);


vec4 color = texture2D(u_texture, vTexCoord+(vec2((dif.r+dif.g+dif.b)*time,0)/resolution));


    gl_FragColor = vec4(color.xyz,1.0);

//gl_FlagColor = color;
}
```

Now I just have to do it for the rest of the axes. The effect actually looks like what it is supposed to do.

I did it for the Y-axis and this is what I got, how do I fix the artifacts, so it seems like the colors actually expand, not simply move.

[breathing thing http://rghost.ru/57475312/image.png](http://rghost.ru/57475312/image.png)

(The shader is only applied to the background image)

Comment: "an average PC, of course" doesn't seem like a definable thing, to me, in 2014. My best guess would be the average of last year's smartphones.

Answer (score 5):

You need to think more like a functional programmer in GLSL. You don't iterate through anything; you supply the function that, given the appropriate inputs, will supply a fragment of the output. The GPU deals with applying that function where appropriate. Subject to vendor-specific extensions, the inputs need to be entirely distinct from the outputs — so inputs are immutable. Also the GPU organises where you're outputting to.

So, no, you wouldn't iterate through anything. And you can't write a shader that picks where it's going to output to, only what it's going to output.

What you probably want to look into is [Stam's Advection](http://www.intpowertechcorp.com/GDC03.pdf) which pretty much inverts the problem. For each output, P, you'll look up a record of where the colours that contribute to it come from. Since you can sample inputs freely (performance concerns aside) you can then collect the appropriate output.

Comment: Seems a little bit advanced to me, but I'll read it and do my best, thank you!

Comment: You should probably also hit Google for "Stam's Advection"; it's a little old but Gamasutra has an article that could be useful: http://www.gamasutra.com/view/feature/1549/practical_fluid_dynamics_part_1.php?print=1

Comment: Sorry, but none of the links helped me :/ Probably to my insufficient level of understanding..